# Xamarin Mac - Get System Information Programmatically

Tags: macos, xamarin, cpu, hardware

I'm trying to get the basic system information in Xamarin Mac Programmatically.

The info I need is:

- Processor (eg.: i7 4700 2.4GHz)
- Ram (eg.: 16GB)
- Disk Size (eg.: 256GB)
- Version (eg.: 13" Retina 2016)

And so on. I checked a couple of articles but in many cases all the info I get are OS Related more than HW related.

eg: 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21835/get-system-information

```
eg: NSDictionary setting = NSDictionary.FromFile ("/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist");  
string os_version_string = (NSString)setting.ValueForKey ((NSString)"ProductVersion");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get most of this information by querying `sysctl`. However, this isn't exposed in the `Darwin` class so you need to do a little bit of `DllImport` yourself.

```cs
[DllImport(Constants.SystemLibrary)]
internal static extern int sysctlbyname(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string property,
    IntPtr output,
    IntPtr oldLen,
    IntPtr newp,
    uint newlen);
```

Then you can get values with:

```cs
public static string GetSystemProperty(string property)
{
    var pLen = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));
    sysctlbyname(property, IntPtr.Zero, pLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
    var length = Marshal.ReadInt32(pLen);
    var pStr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
    sysctlbyname(property, pStr, pLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
    return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pStr);
 }
```

You can list all keys on your machine by running `sysctl -a` in a command line to figure out what to query. So for the information you are looking for you want to do:

```cs
var cpu = GetSystemProperty("machdep.cpu.brand_string");
var ram = GetSystemProperty("hw.memsize");
var macModel = GetSystemProperty("hw.model");
var osVersion = GetSystemProperty("kern.osrelease");
var hostName = GetSystemProperty("kern.hostname");
```

You can get screen information with:

```cs
var screenSize = $"{NSScreen.MainScreen.Frame.Width}x{NSScreen.MainScreen.Frame.Height}";
```

EDIT:

You can get the device serial by querying the IOKit IOPlatformExpertDevice. This code might also work on iOS:

```cs
public static class DeviceSerial
{
    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit")]
    private static extern uint IOServiceGetMatchingService(uint masterPort, IntPtr matching);

    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit")]
    private static extern IntPtr IOServiceMatching(string s);

    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit")]
    private static extern IntPtr IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(uint entry, IntPtr key, IntPtr allocator, uint options);

    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit")]
    private static extern int IOObjectRelease(uint o);

    public static string GetSerial()
    {
        string serial = string.Empty;
        uint platformExpert = IOServiceGetMatchingService(0, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"));
        if (platformExpert != 0)
        {
            NSString key = (NSString)"IOPlatformSerialNumber";
            IntPtr serialNumber = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert, key.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            if (serialNumber != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                serial = NSString.FromHandle(serialNumber);
            }
            IOObjectRelease(platformExpert);
        }
        return serial;
    }
}
```

Then you can get the serial with:

```cs
var serial = DeviceSerial.GetSerial();
```

Comment: Do you maybe know also where can I get the SERIAL NUMBER?
There is a kern.uuid but I don't know if it's os or HW related! thx

Comment: Added a solution to get device serial number